# Update ffmpeg reference to libopencv_core.so version

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I've recently installed OpenCV 3.0 on my machine running Ubuntu 15.04 to do some video manipulations via python. I had some initial problems with the installation, and ended up installing both 2.4 and 3.0 versions separately, uninstalling between each attempt with

```
sudo find / -name "*opencv*" -exec rm -i {} \;
```

I now have a working version of OpenCV 3.0, but it seems my ffmpeg is looking for a 2.4 shared library:

```
ffprobe: error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_core.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My /usr/local/lib folder contains

1. libopencv_core.so
2. libopencv_core.so.3.0
3. libopencv_core.so.3.0.0

I've tried running ldconfig, reinstalling ffmpeg and rebooting, but nothing changes. Is there a way to make OpenCV 3.0 play nicely with ffmpeg, or do I need to have bother a 2.4 version and a 3.0 version installed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you took FFmpeg from the repositories then I had a similar problem on Ubuntu 15.04 between OpenCV2 and FFmpeg as well.

What worked for me remove all of OpenCV and FFmpeg.

Then go to the site of FFmpeg download it and compile it from source.
after that compile OpenCV from source as well. (Both versions, just check each time with the cmake in the reports if FFmpeg = yes and it should work)

If it's not that then its possible that the problem is between the two versions and you should remove one.